# Initialize a base class member variable in derived class with some conditions

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a requirement where I want to initialize a Base class member in derived class.

```
class SuperBase
{
public:
    virtual void Set();
};

class Base:public SuperBase
{
protected:
    int *pVal;
public:
    void Set()
    {
       //Some Logic
    }
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
   // I want to Initialize Base::pVal here and after 
   // that I want to have this value in Set() of Base.
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
  //...Same functionality as Derived1; 
  //...
};

int main()
{
  SuperBase *s = new Derived1; 
  // Here when I create a Derived1 object automatically, 
  // the value for pVal will be initialized 
  s->Set();

 //After calling this Set, I want to get the pVal value access in Set.
}
```

I know that it is an easy thing to do. But these are the things which I cannot use for this problem:

- I cannot use Constructor Initializer List for passing values from derived class to Base [I know that I can easily do this through Constructor Initialiser List but there is a requirement where I don't want the existing Class Constructor]
- I have tried using CRTP[curiously recurring template pattern], but that is also not suitable as it uses a type of static binding, and in higher view, I have to decide at run time which class object to call Derived1,Derived2.
- I also don't want to write any get() in Derived1,Derived2 as I want to only assign values there. This is also a part of my requirement.
- I want the Set logic to be only present in Base class and if there is any special case of Set, then I will override Set in Derived classes, otherwise I will access it from Base.

Any Suggestions??? Any Design Patterns??

Comment: What do you want to initialize it with? `nullptr`?

Comment: No I want to add initialize it with proper values...That values will be diferenr for Derived1 & Derived2

Comment: I must be missing something... Whats stopping you from just assigning to `pVal` in your derived constructors (or anyplace else for that matter)? It's protected, not private; you have access to it. Or is the magic puzzle piece you neglected to mention that `Base` needs it in *its* constructor ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I want to implement this logic in existing code and my Constructor is loaded with lot of initilizer list values, and in this example I have given only one "int*a" actually I have to assign a lot of values. So I want to avoid the Constructor use...

Comment: @Saby So you want to avoid using constructor which is designed for that sort of things and create your own function?

Comment: @Saby "So I want to avoid the Constructor use." - Then your first condition should be "Cannot use constructor.", not "Cannot use constructor initializer list", the latter of which is fulfilled by doing as I mentioned.

Comment: @WhozCraig: OK, If I assign the value in Constructor of Derived Class, then how will I make that value appear in Set() of Base, because that is my ultimate requirement and Set is only in Base, not in Derived..and I dont want to use Initializer List but I can use the constructor..

Comment: Because, it is the same object.   So, though , slightly sub-optimal than initializer list, assigning pVal in Constructor of Derived is ok. So After the construction, the newly created object will have pVal set to appropriate value.

Comment: @Saby You'll forgive the obvious question, but `pVal` is *in the Base class*. I can only assume it will happily read/use `pVal` when `Base::Set()` is invoked. And since you can set it in the constructor (or any other base/derived members since it is, after all, protected), I still don't see what the *problem* is. Seriously, You must be thinking of something that is just not getting through in your question, or you're over-thinking this. Just set it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: My Base class will only be carrying the logic not anything else but the initialisations which will work with logic will only be in derived classes which will be class specific<Derived 1 will have some initialisations, Derived2 has some special initialisations>. So I dont want the initialisations in Derived class.

Comment: @Saby Ok. I think its best I just left it then, as this has left me with some suspicions, but not about derived access to base members: "Derived1 will have some initialisations, Derived2 has some special initialisations. So I dont want the initialisations in Derived class".  um... ok.

Comment: @WhozCraig:Sorry I mistyped it : "I dont want the initialisations in Base class"...I think u also have understood what I meant to say..

Comment: @Saby I understand, and I'll give you this. A fundamental rule of objects and their member data management is this: The either they own and manage the data internally, or provide some manageable interface for derivations and consumers of the object to do so. The design you have and the restrictions you have emplaced have but-one-remaining possible path to provide such access; direct member variable modification by derived classes with no functional interface to act as the go-between in the Base. Its really all you have given what you're restrictions entail, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, You could do this way:

Option 1 :
a) Override the Set() in Derived1;

b) In Derived1::Set,
   -- assign the pVal desired value.

-- Call Base::Set

Sample code:

```
void Derived::Set(){
    pVal = /*some value*/;

    Base::Set(); 

}
```

Option 2: As pointed by Angew

```
class Derived1: public Base
{
 public:
  Derived()
  {
    pVal = /*some value*/;
  }
};
```

The `SuperBase *s = new Derived1;`  will invoke the above constructor and `pVal` would be set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...Sorry...I missed one point in my question, I will update that in the question. Actually I want the Set logic to be only present in Base class and if there is any special case of Set, then I will override Set in Derived classes, otherwise I will access it from Base. +1 for ur answer though!!

Answer (score 1):

You can only *initialise* a data member of a class in a member-initialiser-list of that class's constructor. There's no other way. So if you need initialisation, you'll have to add an appropriate constructor to `Base` and use it (it can be `protected`, of course).

On the other hand, if it would be enough for your purposes to *assign* a value into `pVal` (after it's been initialised by `Base`'s constructor), you can simply do that in the body of the constructor of `Derived1` and `Derived2`:

```
class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
  Derived()
  {
    pVal = whatever;
  }
};
```

Comment: +1 This is the only thing that makes any sense to me given the constrictions of the problem (which are obtuse at-best).

Comment: @WhozCraig: I know that I am having too many constrictions, if it wouldnt have been there, I may also wouldnt have asked for your help, but as I am out of ideas, so trying to get help from you people...

Comment: @Saby I understand completely. Are you familiar with what an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is? Sometimes it *really* helps to step back to basics and rethink things.

Comment: @WhozCraig: In my question, I have clearly mentioned about my requirements/restrictions and I think I have explained "Why I am imposing this restriction?" and if you need to clarify anything from me regarding please ask...I am not falling into X-Y problem... You can ask me questions and I am ready to answer your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Create constructors for this purpose.

```
class Base: public SuperBase {
public:
    Base() : pVal(0) {} // Default constructor
protected:
    int *pVal;
    Base(int* Val = 0 /* default value */) : pVal(Val) {} // special constructor
    ...
};

class Derived1: public Base {
public:
   Derived1() : Base(p1 /* Set whatever you want here */) {
   }
};

class Derived2: public Base {
public:
   Derived2() : Base(p2 /* Set other value here */) {
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another level of inheritance, between the `Derived1`/`Derived2` classes and the `Base` class, who has a constructor initializing `pVal`.